# Compress a binary matrix

Tags: php, compression

I have to send a [large set of data](https://shrt.cf/7py) containing biological samples which are two-dimensional **`SQUARE`** array of 1's and 0's.
Say for example:

```
[
  [0,1,0],
  [1,0,0],
  [0,0,0]
]
```

So- this was 3-dimensional. Mine goes 60-70 and expected to go to 120 rows/columns (max). I have to send this via Ajax/API and also store into database.
I could serialise as Json- But I was looking if there was an optimal way to handle things like this. Like, with a series of proper compression/decompression?

One way I could think of it is:

1. Join the digits as string
2. Divide in clusters of 6 digits. **111111 bin = 63 dec ( A-Z, a-z, 0-9,_ = 26 + 26 + 10 + 1)**
3. Convert each cluster to alphanumeric encoding (a-zA-Z0-9_) and join as string

How smart/stupid/optimal is this solution? Is something better already out there?

Comment: If the matrix is mostly 0s you could just send the co-ordinates of the 1s.

Comment: If the data structure is fixed you may serialize them into a very long binary number, then use GMP to convert it to octets, and then convert it again to base64 encoded string for sending.

Comment: You need to provide more information on the content. Does the distribution of 1's and 0's appear random? Is it biased to more 1's or more 0's? Are patterns repeated? There are three dimensions, but you gave two: 60-70 and 120. What is the third?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting your data structure to JSON, then passing it through a standard compression algorithm like [`gzdeflate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php) is about as simple as you can get, and will result in excellent compression ratios. There's probably no reason to make it any more complicated than that.

(The output of `gzdeflate` will be binary data. If you need to transfer it over a channel which can't deal with that, you can `base64_encode` it; the results will still be smaller than the original JSON for a matrix of any meaningful size.)

"Flattening" the matrix into a single string of `1`s and `0`s (and storing the dimensions of the original matrix alongside the string) before compressing it may give you slightly better compression ratios, but at the expense of making your code more complicated.

Performing alphanumeric encoding on the matrix like you're describing in your question will result in **significantly worse** compression ratios, as it will make it very difficult for the DEFLATE algorithm to detect any patterns in your data which don't "line up" perfectly with the size of your clusters.